# How to prevent Child Window from thrashing the Parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I show a link in my Page (Parent) which when clicked, pops a new window(Child Window)

The child window contains this Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.name = "parentWin";
    var manipulate = document.referrer != null && (document.referrer.indexOf('upd.caqh.org') > -1);
    if (window.opener != null && manipulate) {
        if (window.opener.opener != null) {
            window.opener.opener = null;
        }
        window.opener.location.href = "/OAS/Default.aspx?DCS_Relogon=1";
        window.opener = null;
        this.window.close();
    }
</script>
```

This closes the child and makes it to appear in my Parent window. I don't wan't this to happen.

My Question is,

Is there any way by which we can prevent the child window from overriding the parent window?

I don't want to use "`onbeforeunload`" because I don't want to pop an alert in the page.

Comment: so why are you using these lines of code `window.opener.location.href = "/OAS/Default.aspx?DCS_Relogon=1";
window.opener = null;
this.window.close();`

Comment: @anurupr : The child window is a 3rd party page and that code was written by them.

Comment: do you know what it does?

Comment: window.opener returns a reference to the window that created the window and window.opener.location.href=url changes the Parent Window URL

Comment: `this.window.close();` closes the popup window. so if you don't want it to close, you need to make sure that line is not there

Comment: Found the answer. visit
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121328/how-to-disconnect-javascript-popup-from-opener>