# Prevent accessing parent window from child window using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I show the links of different websites in my Page which when clicked, pops a new window.

All are working fine except one which creates trouble for me. say,when I click the link( eg, hyperlink for www.example.com), a new window pops out and when I press a HTML link from that page, the pop-up closes and the Parent window is loaded with that website( www.example.com ).

They have something in their code like

```
window.opener.location.href = "www.example.com";
this.window.close();
```

Is there any way by which we can prevent the child window from overriding the parent window?I don't want to use "onbeforeunload" because I don't want to pop an alert in the page.

**Adding the Code snippet**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.name = "parentWin";
    var manipulate = document.referrer != null && (document.referrer.indexOf('upd.caqh.org') > -1);
    if (window.opener != null && manipulate) {
        if (window.opener.opener != null) {
            window.opener.opener = null;
        }
        window.opener.location.href = "/OAS/Default.aspx?DCS_Relogon=1";
        window.opener = null;
        this.window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Found the answer. visit
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121328/how-to-disconnect-javascript-popup-from-opener>

Answer (score 0):

Will you please provide a brief code?
As i know window.open()can use from the destination window to return details of the source (parent) window.

```
this.window.close();
```

Here, you might be  referring to the class or id of page, which might be resulting in closing that page..

Comment: I added the code snippet